# bluetooth problem : Bluetooth and Nokia Symbian

Tags: bluetooth

I have Nokia E63, laptop ASUS X452C with Linux 14.04 LTS and Bluetooth UBS Dongle.

When I wanted to shared photo from My handphone to Laptop, and fail. My handphone unable share photo to laptop. There are "Transmission failed".

Anyone can solve my Problem?

Comment: How do you share photo from your phone to the laptop? Did you use "Browse file" and do a copy paste?

Comment: For first, yes. But Fail....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search dash for "Personal File Sharing" and set to allow incoming files to the computer

Comment: Thank's, I dunno this before, because I new  at Linux. So, I litle bit know about Linux Features ^_^

Comment: Click the icon in the top left of the screen, looks like the ubuntu logo and enter 'personal file sharing' and see if the search shows the program, the program should bring up a window similar to this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/chvaum60926owu0/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-02%2005%3A23%3A25.png?dl=0

Comment: this did not worked for me in ubuntu 16.10. I managed to pair the samsung galaxy s4 (android) but i cannot receive or send files. I made the sharing enabled but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because the Ubuntu don't have the configurations for symbian phones. I've tried connecting my Blackberry 9360 with my laptop. Its got connected but it can't also send files to my ubuntu. Because this don't have the configuration settings for Blackberry.
 Then I tried connecting my android with the my laptop. I connected the android and then went to bluetooth settings by right clicking on the bluetooth indicator on the top and then choosing **Bluetooth settings...** at the end. There you click on your proper device and then check the option **Receive Files** and then you are good to go. 
But I don't think if you can send files using your symbian phone. Because you need to install right drivers or configuration settings.

Comment: Thank's to explain this, but I don't have Android phone T~T